# Underline the main header when the sub header is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div id=wrapDesktopNavBar>
    <ul class="desktopNavBar">
        <li><a class="firstLevel" href="#">header 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a onclick....></a><a class="firstLevel" href="#">header 2</a> 
            <ul>
                <li><a class="secondLevel" href="#">1st sub header</a> 
                    <li><a class="secondLevel" href="#">2nd sub header</a> 
                        <li><a class="secondLevel" href="#">3rd sub header</a> 
            </ul>
            <li><a class="firstLevel" href="#">header 3</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.mainNavSection').hide();
    $('.desktopNavBar a').bind('click', function (e) {
        $('.desktopNavBar a.current').removeClass('current');
        $('.mainNavSection:visible').hide();
        $(this.hash).show();
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $(this).closest('.desktopNavBar > li').find('a:first').addClass('current');
        e.preventDefault();
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Hi the above is my html and javascript. I have a class called "current" which simply underlines the header and its subheader when it's being clicked. I want to allow the main header to be underlined when the sub header is being clicked. I've tried `$(this).closest('.desktopNavBar > li').find('a:first').addClass('current');` but it only underlines the first a tag and not the second a tag. I want the 2nd  tag to be underlined. And, i can't swap my 2nd  tag with my 1st a because it affects smth else.

is there soemthing like `.find(a:second)` to allow me to add class to the 2nd a tag?

Comment: you can do `find('a.firstLevel')` as you already have a class for the `second` item

Comment: Oh yea it works now! I was testing the same solution that you suggested just now and for some reason, it didn't work. i must have refreshed the wrong local host. thanks much :)